# Scala, mutable.Stack iterate till is empty

Tags: scala, iterator, stack

i have scala code that looks something like:

```
while(selectStack.nonEmpty) {
  val n = selectStack.pop()

  // do something with N

}
```

There's a better scala-way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are lots of higher-order methods you can use, such as `foreach`

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Stack
val s = Stack(1,2,3,4)   
s.foreach(n=>println(n*2))                        //> 2
                                                  //| 4
                                                  //| 6
                                                  //| 8
```

or `map`

```
 s.map(_*3) 
 // > res0: scala.collection.immutable.Stack[Int] = Stack(3, 6, 9, 12)
```

Comment: the Stack must be mutable, and drain the items while the iteration ocurrs

Comment: Ah, then no, I don't think there's anything that's much cleaner than what you have. The only method that removes an item is `pop`.

Comment: After iterating, you can `s.clear()`. Presumably, someone else used stack operations in constructing it, but you seem to be the sole consumer now and no one is pushing anymore.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't drain items during the iteration. Maybe the code that 'does something with n' calls code that examines the stack again (I've done this kind of thing writing graph-processing code for parser generators)